# Displaying time with milliseconds 09:15:10.001

Tags: time, milliseconds

I have a table with a field of type TIME which is usually displayed HH:MM:SS, but I need to display it as HH:MM:SS.### where the ### are milliseconds. This is because it is recording processes and many processes happen in a single second, so when I display the order I need it precise. So my questions are: 1) is the TIME type the correct field type to be able to do this? And 2) if yes, then how would I display it?

Comment: You are missing to explain in which programming language you need to resolve the doubt.

Comment: The `time` datatype in SQL is for time of day (not for a duration).

Comment: I am using php MySQL

Comment: Add a tag for your programming language. Maybe add mention in title or body.